# How to replace HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play with a function that return the media url

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I'm trying to intercept network requests made by JSDOM, I managed to intercept most of network requests by changing their resourceLoader function which allowed me to intercept all urls of requests.

That is except for media resouces because JSDOM doesn't support  HTMLMediaElement, so for media resources the requests are not even made for me to interecept them using resourceLoader function. The work around suggested through reading their github issues is to write my own  HTMLMediaElement function that I'm interested in.

All I want to achieve here to get the media url, so I want to replace  HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play with a function that returns or console.log the url of the media that it is trying to play.

I wrote this simple function, but I can't figure how to access the resource url.

```
window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype.load = () => {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(arguments);
};
```